# Image is being placed on top of navigation submenu

Tags: html, css

while designing my website (for my school project), I find that my image keeps being placed on top of my navigation submenu when activated. Any help with what to do?

[Here is a visual picture of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJHVG.png)

On a side note: any suggestions on which styles to wrap the text into a div/p tag to align properly by the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want your image of the laptop to stay behind your navbar, right?
If so, then you have so use the z-index CSS property.

Reference for it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

The higher the z-index, the further forward it will be placed. An element with z-index:100 will be displayed on top of an element with z-index:99 and below.

Set the z-index of your navbar to be 100 or so, then you're sure it will always be in the front, like such:

```
.nav {
     z-index:100;
}
```

Add this code to your navbar css, and it should help.

Good luck with your school project!

Best regards, Kevin